# Dynamically instantiated prefabs are invisible

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, instantiation

Now I know that this is a common problem and there are so many mistakes that would lead to it, but I have searched and seen all the results and answers in unity forums and other websites, and I'm sure that I don't have any beginner-mistake that would lead to it.

My problem is -Like the title states- that I have a "platform" prefab and I have a script, attached to some game object in the scene, that instantiates a new platform every x seconds. Now, the scripts works and everything is fine, the platforms are instantiated and they are moving and functioning as they should, but I can't see anything from this!

I mean that I can see them in the scene view window, where everything is fine, but in the game view window nothing appears, though I can interact with the platforms, such as landing on them and so on...

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you tried to move back `Camera` or use Layers to prioritize some objects?

Comment: @Morasiu Thanks for your help :). Actually my spawn point was on 0 position on the z-axis and my camera on -10. but when I made the spawn point object a child to the camera, I forgot that the 0 will be relative to the cameras position, so now both of them have the same position on z-axis and that's why the platform can't be seen :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the z depth... your probably instantiating them behind your camera. a good way to check is to start the game, go to scene, and take it out of 2d, then click one of the platforms in the explorer, and check its z value

Answer (score 0):

It is highly possible that they are shown "behind" your background. I was making an android app and my buttons were displayed behind the UI panel. Try to instantiate your platforms as child objects of your panel.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but I don't have a background here. anyway I found out that the camera and the platforms have the same position on z axis because my spawn point s a child of the camera! and that's the problem thanks again :)